# Crossfading images in some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to crossfade images that change automatically after a certain time interval. I checked the code in safari and chrome and it worked well in safari. However, in chrome it works well initially but then the crossfading doesn't happen at certain times and the image flashes and changes. Can somebody tell me why or suggest any changes.

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img" >
    <img src="img/slider/3.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

And the jquery is

```
$(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000).next('img').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Seems like it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/pxoggtfd/

Comment: I was trying a cross fading effect.Similar to the ones shown here:http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/